# ¿Cómo sumar dígitos en pascal?

Tags: pascal

```
program eje10p3;
var
CONT,dig,suma:integer;
procedure leerentero(var n:integer);
begin
read(n);
cont:=cont+1;
suma:=0;
while (n div 10 <> 0) do
 begin
  CONT:=CONT+1;
  dig:=n mod 10;
  n:=n div 10;
  dig:=dig+dig;
  suma:=suma+dig;
 end;
end;
var entero:integer;
begin
    leerentero(entero);
    writeln ('la cantidad de digitos es ',CONT);
    writeln ('la suma de digitos es ',suma);
end.
```

Este es mi código, no suma,no resta, no divide, no multiplica, no saca raíz, no saca factor común, no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta es?
1)  La línea   did:=dig+dig;   realmene no la necesitas.
2)  Al salir del bucle te falta sumar el último elemento n.

Comment: Te recomiendo también leer esta sección:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask